# Why this StringFormat is not working?

Tags: wpf, string-formatting

I have a DevXPress GridControl bound to an observable collection. I want to format "WorkedHours" but somehow is not working so the result looks ugly. This is the code:

```
        <dxg:GridControl  ItemsSource="{Binding Result}">
            <dxg:GridControl.TotalSummary>
                <dxg:GridSummaryItem SummaryType="Sum" FieldName="Worked" DisplayFormat="0.0"/>
            </dxg:GridControl.TotalSummary>
            <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                <dxg:GridColumn Header="Month" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Month}" Visible="{Binding Path=GroupByMonth}" Width="80"/>
                <dxg:GridColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Visible="{Binding Path=ShowName}" Width="220"/>
                <dxg:GridColumn Header="Project code" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ProjectCode}" Visible="{Binding Path=ShowProjects}" Width="80" />
                <dxg:GridColumn Header="Project description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ProjectDescription}" Visible="{Binding Path=ShowProjects}" Width="270"/>
                <dxg:GridColumn Header="Wbs code" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=WbsCode}" Visible="{Binding Path=ShowWbs}" Width="80" />
                <dxg:GridColumn Header="Wbs description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=WbsDescription}" Visible="{Binding Path=ShowWbs}"  Width="270" />
                <dxg:GridColumn Header="Comment" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Comment}" Visible="{Binding Path=ShowComment}"  Width="270" />
                <dxg:GridColumn Header="Worked hours" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Worked,StringFormat=\{0\:N0\}}"  Width="100" FieldName="Worked" />
            </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridControl.View>
                <dxg:TableView AllowGrouping="True" ShowAutoFilterRow="True" ShowTotalSummary="True"/>
            </dxg:GridControl.View>
        </dxg:GridControl>
```

Any ideas about how to fix it? Thanks a lot. I've tried different formatting options but none of them is working as one would expect.

Comment: Can you please try `StringFormat='{}{0:N0}'` and see if this works in your Worked Hours column as this may be escape problem for '{' chars.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that too. I think it's not a matter of StringFormat syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in DevExpress, see the following link:

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q257296.aspx

They advice to use the `GridColumn.EditSettings` attached property instead ..

Answer (score 1):

Change your StringFormat => `StringFormat=N0`

Comment: Thanks. I tried that too. I think it's not a matter of StringFormat syntax.